# AFUI/Intels Appframework scrollers not working in phonegap Android

Tags: javascript, html, appmobi

In a Phonegap 3.1.0 app I use Intels app framework 2.0, which works like a charm, most of the time. The IOS app works sublime as I say so myself, but the Android app is showing some discrepancies. First and foremost, it is not sizing like it should.

I have a header (floating at the top) which is 100% wide and outside the panels from afui. This header sizes perfect. It is side to side just like it should be. Which means the sizing of phonegap works fine.

But the afui div, which holds the panels, has extra padding on the side and doesn't size well in general. It has space on the left, right, top and bottom which is not defined in the CSS. It almost seems like it's 75% of the original size.

Further more, no scroller works for some reason. None at all.

So this makes me believe that there is a problem when starting the $.ui. But the funny thing is, it fires without warnings.

So I'm at whits end. Anybody got a sane answer to this? Can it be order of js calls, and if so, what order is recommended.

Comment: can you share the code, i can help with the issue

Comment: I already found where the problem lies. There is a massive inconstancy in CSS between IOS and Android. Where IOS is really forgiving, Android will kill you instantly and thus not show some pieces. I'll figure it out, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

if your scroller it not working then append a div next to your panel, like in below example -

```
<div title="hello" data-defer="xyx.html" class="panel">
  <div class="lmn"></div>
</div>
```

and now load or render your data in 'lmn' class div.